# Default filter on ag-grid for angular 2+

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Im using the default filtering on ag-grid. However the timing between typing and filtering is too fast.  Is there a way to slow this down or instead of basing it on typing stopped to start the filter, do it based on a button press in the filter popup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a property of `colDef` object: `filterParams: { ebounceMs: 500 }`. See the official ag-grid [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/filtering/#filter-parameters).
Here is my quick example for `Age` with denounce time 3sec. https://plnkr.co/edit/SxxW8Oo8IzssLNOt